# Rails Validation For Nested Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-forms

I'm using Rails 3.2 and 4.

I have a Survey and I want to validate that each question has between 2 and 5 answers.  Survey has_many Questions, Questions has_many Answers and belongs to Survey.  Answer belongs to Question.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Question model

```
validate :answer_count


def answer_count
  self.errors[:base] << "Can have answers only between 2 and 5" if answers.length<1 || answers.length>5
end
```